# FCM Subscribe Topic return Invalid Token

Tags: firebase, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging

The problem is as stated above. If I try to subscribe to a push notification via the url: `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/{token}/rel/topics/{topic}`, I always get the following response: `{"error":"InvalidToken"}`

I have tried using both `GET` and `POST` methods but still the same response.

I have checked if the Token is a valid token by using the following url: `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/{token}` which return the correct data like this:

```
{
    "application": "com.chrome.windows",
    "subtype": "wp:http://localhost/#2A58747F-DEF7-4C55-8073-126B2D168-V2",
    "authorizedEntity": "856365479457",
    "platform": "WEBPUSH"
}
```

If my token is valid, then why I am getting the error invalid token?

Comment: Are you positive that you're using the correct Server Key (associated with the `856365479457` project)?

Comment: @AL that entity ID is the messagingServer ID? Then no, its different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are hitting a `GET` request with topic subscribe, try `POST` with the same parameters.

Or you are hitting incorrect url: Hitting an url without `../rel/..` also produces the same error.

## Error

[image: Similar Error]

## Solution

[image: Solution]

Comment: I tried it via AJAX and it works. But via PostMan it gives an error.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with your postman. I tried with both postman and advanced rest client, it works fine on both.

Comment: What is <REGISTRATION_TOKEN> in  https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/<REGISTRATION_TOKEN>/rel/topics/<TOPIC_NAME> ?

At https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic